# How To Mapping Multipart file to DTO using Spring Boot for incoming request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, upload

I have this DTO Request Class

```
Public Class MyRequestDTO(){

private String name;

private MultipartFile docPic;

}
```

i want to retrieve in in controller

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public String test(@RequestBody MyRequestDTO dto){

system.out.print(dto.getdocPic.getOriginalFileName());

return "success;
}
```

but always get javaNullexception when i try to display this newly requested file, is it correct to mapping multipart file inside DTO ?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest spring boot we have a running example without the @RequestBody annotation, so try this:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public String test(MyRequestDTO dto){
```

If that doesn't work, the next spot you should double check is your request. Specifically the `Content-type`. The above signature works for us with a request that has a content type of: `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Also, I think you wanted to hide your actual code and wrote a similar version here, but it would be great if it were valid JAVA, otherwise it was distracting for me to read :) ... Example: `Public Class MyRequestDTO()`, `return "success;`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting javaNullexception because you're receiving MyRequestDTO dto as null or some property of dto object is pointing to null.

So please be sure before calling the getter method on a null object.

Firstly get that dto.getdocPic is not pointing to null.

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public String test(@RequestBody MyRequestDTO dto){

    if(dto.getdocPic() != null){
        
         system.out.print(dto.getdocPic().getOriginalFileName());
    }

    return "success;

}
```